# doctrine2 mapping overwrite inherited inversedBy field from MappedSuperclass

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, mapping

another question. I have a abstract BaseLog Entity which keeps the association to my user.
In addition I have 2 Entities (FooLog & BarLog) which extend BaseLog. In addition I have my User Entity which are suppose to hold two associations to Log. One for FooLog and one for BarLog. Here is my issue. I get error messages because I don't know how to overwrite BaseLog's inversedBy field in extending Entity. Could you please help me.

Because I think my explanation is not really good, here the Set up of my entities.

**BaseLog**

```
/** @ORM\MappedSuperclass */
abstract class BaseLog {
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="logs")
   * @ORM\JoinColumns({
   *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
   * })
   */
  private $user;
}
```

**FooLog**

```
/** @ORM\Entity */
class FooLog extends BaseLog {
  // Some additional fields
}
```

**BarLog**

```
/** @ORM\Entity */
class BarLog extends BaseLog {
  // Some additional fields
}
```

**User**

```
/** @ORM\Entity */
class User {
  /**
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="FooLog", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist"})
   */
  private $fooLogs;

  /**
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="BarLog", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist"})
   */
  private $barLogs;
}
```

How do I have to overwrite *BaseLog*'s *inversedBy* in *FooLog* & *BarLog*.

I get several Mapping error on this set up:
BaseLog

- **BaseLog:** The association BaseLog#user refers to the inverse side field User#logs which does not exist.
- **FooLog:** The association FooLog#user refers to the inverse side field User#logs which does not exist.
- **BarLog:** The association BarLog#user refers to the inverse side field User#logs which does not exist.
- **User:** The mappings User#fooLogs and FooLog#user are incosistent with each other.
- **User:** The mappings User#barLogs and BarLog#user are incosistent with each other.

Please help me to get my mapping sorted.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm facing a similar situation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overriding inversedBy mapping in Doctrine 2 inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745653/overriding-inversedby-mapping-in-doctrine-2-inheritance)

Comment: @hafichuk, there is a duplicated question with an excellent answer over there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22820964/37706

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had similar issue with single inheritance. I resolved this by defining same association in both entity classes (parent and inherited) but with different name. In your case you can try this:

```
    /** @ORM\Entity */
class FooLog extends BaseLog {
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="foologs")
   * @ORM\JoinColumns({
   *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
   * })
   */
   private $user;
}
```

and in class BarLog:

```
/** @ORM\Entity */
    class BarLog extends BaseLog {
      /**
       * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="barlogs")
       * @ORM\JoinColumns({
       *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
       * })
       */
       private $bar_user;
    }
```

Notice different name ($bar_user).
You also have to define foologs and barlogs properties in user entity. This removes doctrine validation errors.

Answer (score 3):

I have struggled with the same issue using [Single Table Inheritance](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance). As far as I can tell there isn't a solution to it. Even though `inversedBy` is considered compulsory, it seems you can get away with ignoring it. However, as the Doctrine docs suggest the performance deteriorates rapidly.

`@AssociationOverride` doesn't help, because you can't modify association definitions, only database column properties.

I've tried a number of options, none of which are satisfactory.

**Update:** I still haven't been able to find any solution to these sorts of errors when running `app/console doctrine:schema:validate`.

```
[Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'Acme\AcmeBundle\Entity\CourseLocation' mapping is invalid:
* The field Acme\AcmeBundle\Entity\CourseLocation#facilitators is on the inverse side of a bi-directional relationship, but the specified mappedBy association on the target-entity Acme\AcmeBundle\Entity\CourseFacilitatorResponsibility#courseLocation does not contain the required 'inversedBy' attribute.
```

In this instance `CourseFacilitatorResponsibility` is a sub-class (with single table inheritance) of `CourseResponsibility`. `CourseLocation` refers to multiple `CourseResponsibility` entities. I think uni-directional associations is the only way around it.

Comment: I also run into this problem. Is there any solution by now?

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do this (since Doctrine 2.3) is using [`AssociationOverrides`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/tutorials/override-field-association-mappings-in-subclasses.html).

Remove `inversedBy="logs"` from `BaseLog` class - since a mapped super class doesn't represent a real entity anyway - and then override it in subclasses. Here's how that should look:

**BaseLog**

```
/** @ORM\MappedSuperclass */
abstract class BaseLog {
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
   * @ORM\JoinColumns({
   *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
   * })
   */
  private $user;
}
```

**FooLog**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity */
 * @ORM\AssociationOverrides({
 *     @ORM\AssociationOverride(name="user", inversedBy="fooLogs")
 * })
 */
class FooLog extends BaseLog {
  // Some additional fields
}
```

**BarLog**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity */
 * @ORM\AssociationOverrides({
 *     @ORM\AssociationOverride(name="user", inversedBy="barLogs")
 * })
 */
class BarLog extends BaseLog {
  // Some additional fields
}
```

`name=` in `@ORM\AssociationOverride` represents the field you want to override from the mapped super class.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC there was not good way to override mappings in older versions of Doctrine. In Doctrine >= 2.2 there is something called [association override](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#association-override) so maybe you can use it.

BTW Why do you not want move associations from base to concrete classes and define valid inversedBy then ?

Comment: I would like to keep the association in BaseLog because it is every time same except the var name in for User entity.

Comment: I had a look in provided documentation but I can't find how to override inversedBy field. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Doc link is dead.
Also, using "current" rather than "latest" seem a wiser choice, since it will point to an actually released version.
New link [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/current/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#association-override)