# Overriding inversedBy mapping in Doctrine 2 inheritance

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have the following entity:

```php
class Restaurant
{
    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="CollectionTime", mappedBy="restaurant")
     */
    protected $collectionTimes;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="DeliveryTime", mappedBy="restaurant")
     */
    protected $deliveryTimes;
}
```

Mapping to two subclasses of the same entity:

```php
/**
 * @Entity
 * @InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *   "CollectionTime" = "CollectionTime",
 *   "DeliveryTime"   = "DeliveryTime"
 * })
 */
abstract class OrderTime
{
    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Restaurant")
     */
    protected $restaurant;
}

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class CollectionTime extends OrderTime
{
}

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class DeliveryTime extends OrderTime
{
}
```

Now the problem is, `doctrine orm:validate-schema` reports the following errors:

> - The field Restaurant#collectionTimes is on the inverse side of a bi-directional relationship, but the specified mappedBy association on the target-entity CollectionTime#restaurant does not contain the required 'inversedBy=collectionTimes' attribute.
> - The field Restaurant#deliveryTimes is on the inverse side of a bi-directional relationship, but the specified mappedBy association on the target-entity DeliveryTime#restaurant does not contain the required 'inversedBy=deliveryTimes' attribute.

In short, Doctrine expects every `mappedBy` to have an `inversedBy` on the other side.

The only solution I can see so far is to move the `OrderTime::$restaurant` property and mapping to `CollectionTime` and `DeliveryTime`, just to be able to add the proper `inversedBy` mapping:

```php
abstract class OrderTime
{
}

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class CollectionTime extends OrderTime
{
    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Restaurant", inversedBy="collectionTimes")
     */
    protected $restaurant;
}

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class DeliveryTime extends OrderTime
{
    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Restaurant", inversedBy="deliveryTimes")
     */
    protected $restaurant;
}
```

But it is cumbersome and goes against the principle of inheritance.

**Is there a way to just override the `inversedBy` attribute in the subclasses, without having to (re)declare the whole property in the subclass?**

I've looked into [@AssociationOverrides](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#association-override) and [@AttributeOverrides](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#attribute-override), but they don't seem to be designed for this purpose.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can override `inversedBy` since Doctrine 2.6. That would look like that:

```php
/**
 * @Entity
 * @ORM\AssociationOverrides({
 *     @ORM\AssociationOverride(name="restaurant", inversedBy="collectionTimes")
 * })
 */
class CollectionTime extends OrderTime
{
}

/**
 * @Entity
 * @ORM\AssociationOverrides({
 *     @ORM\AssociationOverride(name="restaurant", inversedBy="deliveryTimes")
 * })
 */
class DeliveryTime extends OrderTime
{
}
```

Answer (score 8):

#### Unidirectional / bidirectional

Doctrine 2 uses the concept of *unidirectional* associations and *bidirectional* associations.

When defining a unidirectional association you have to omit the `inversedBy` parameter, because the association isn't inversed.

When defining a bidirectional association you have to use the `inversedBy` parameter on the *owning side* (that's the side that actually contains all metadata for Doctrine to properly map the association), and you have to use the `mappedBy` parameter on the *inversed side* (so that Doctrine knows where to look for the actual mapping metadata for the association).

So you either use both `inversedBy` *and* `mappedBy` (bidirectional) or you *don't* use them at all (unidirectional).

#### Principle of inheritance

> But it is cumbersome and goes against the principle of inheritance.

I think that depends on how you look at it:

If you only look at the code (not the mapping), you are correct. Both concrete implementations of `OrderTime` share a property `$restaurant` (and probably getters, setters, and maybe other logic), so the principle dictates that you define that in `OrderTime`.

But when you look at the mapping, you have 2 *different* associations: One that ties `Restaurant::$collectionTimes` and `CollectionTime::$restaurant` together, and one that ties `Restaurant::$deliveryTimes` and `DeliveryTime::$restaurant` together.

Because these are 2 different associations, it's only fair that Doctrine wants you to properly define them both.

You can still stick to principle of inheritance in the following way: Define all shared logic you need in `OrderTime`, even the property `$restaurant`, just don't add the mapping metadata. In the concrete implementations you can redeclare the property `$restaurant` with the proper mapping metadata.

The only reason you have to redeclare the property `$restaurant` in those concretes is that you're using Annotations for mapping metadata. When using Yaml or XML, you don't have to redeclare the property because the mapping metadata will be in separate files.

So in fact it's not code/logic you're defining in those concrete implementations, it's the mapping metadata.

#### Value Object

Those `OrderTime` classes look more like [Value Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object) to me (not Entities): [A small simple object, like money or a date range, whose equality isn't based on identity.](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/valueObject.html)

Doctrine will support Value Objects starting with version 2.5 ([see here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-93)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm awarding the bounty to avoid any chance to lose it, even though I have a few comments ;-)

Comment: To me, the mapping should not be taken into account when considering whether this goes against the principle of inheritance, so there really is only one way to look at it. Regarding the value object, I don't think they are TBH, but I would be happy if you could prove me I'm wrong, with some example code! Anyway, the feature you mention seems to only allow mapping of a single VO, not collections of VO yet, so I think it's mostly irrelevant for now.

Comment: About inheritance: Doctrine kind of forces you into this setup (but only when using annotations). It also requires an association to have 2 fixed endpoints, so you cannot have one side sometimes point to entity A, other times to entity B :(

Comment: About value objects: I based this on the names of the entities (`OrderTime`) and don't have insight to their implementation, so I could be off here :)

Comment: Thanks, to summarize your answer, I can either change to another mapping driver (XML or YAML), or declare the non-mapped property in the parent class, and redeclare the property in both child classes (my preferred method so far). I will also probably open a feature request to be able to override the `inversedBy` parameter in the child classes; if you're right and doing what I want is possible with the other mapping drivers, it should be logically feasible also with the annotation driver!

Comment: In the other drivers you need to specify the "field name" (=property) you want to map. Annotations are defined in the doc-block of that property, so the annotation driver will simply use that property as "field name". So even if you want to be able to override the `inversedBy` parameter, you still need that property in order to have a doc-block in order to define the override ;)

Comment: PS: I would also prefer placing everything in the parent, and redeclare the property in the children for sake of the annotations. Just view it as mapping-metadata and it won't "hurt" that much ;) You're definitely _not_ introducing any logic that should be in the parent this way.

Comment: I agree, even though I'd be better off without the extra properties, just for the sake of the cleanliness of my code :)

Comment: Did you ever find a proper solution to this? I have the exact same situation. However, I want to query OrderTime and join the restaurant on it. This is not possible when the Restaurant is in the child classes: OrderTime has no association named Restaurant. Any clues?

Comment: Never mind, [this is possible](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/4887) as of Doctrine 2.6.